# Word 2007 - two digital signatures (with a change in between)

Tags: microsoft-word, digital-signature

In Word 2007, I'm trying to create a form for providing a procedure to deviate from rules.

A user would enter some information and sign the form. Someone else would then select *APPROVED* or *REJECTED* from a combo box and sign it.

However, the change of status would invalidate the first signature.

The only thing I can think of is to have the person approving sign first, followed swiftly by the author.  This would be odd, though, if the dates were different.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: If I recall, PDF documents can do exactly this – the signatures and changes are layered; signature A signs the original, signature B signs the [original + sig A + changes since A], and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a workaround.

Create two signature boxes for the supervisory stage, one labelled "Approved" and one "Rejected".
The manager then digitally signs one or the other.

[image: Signature Boxes]

This way, the document isn't changed between the two signatures and so the first signature is not invalidated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure now that this is the only way to maintain the chronology.  I've just discovered that there's a discontinued product called InfoPath in which section-based signatures were possible, but not in Word.  Technically someone could come along and sign the other box at a later date, but that's not much of a concern.

Comment: If you select the "Show sign date in signature line" option when creating the signature box, that should show if someone has signed the other box at a later time.

Comment: Even without that option, the date is still shown in the signatures pane.  I'll add a note that says only one box must be signed and if both are, then the form is invalid.  Also, each form instance will be revision controlled, giving an extra layer of protection against unauthorised editing.